# Equivalent boolean expressions with truth table in Java

Tags: java, parsing, logic, boolean-expression, truthtable

**I want to verify, that one boolean expression is mathematically equivalent to another.**

Let's say, we have 3 boolean variables: `a, b, c`.
The expression `X = ((a || b) && !c)`.
Then I rewrite some code, and it turns out, that `Y = !(((!a && !b) || c) && true)`.

**My questions**:

- Is there a possibility to verify on the fly, that expressions X and Y are the same for all input?
- Is there a possibility to compact the expressions, so that Y gets simplified?
- I want to see the truth table for X, Y with inputs a, b, c.

*Disclaimer*: I know, that i can write a program for different inputs of the variables and the output of X and Y. I thought more of a syntax parser, that might probably also parse other variables (e.g. `n<100`) instead of just `a`, so that I can paste code of if-statements as input.

Greetings and thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: Why on earth did you stick an `&& true` in your second expression? Why only one `&& true`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so I can ask for simplification :-)